# Python looping for label variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a loop that will display each title of product for their individual labels (Tkinter module).

With the current loop i can get it to print my 10 "static_webpage_1_titles" in the list, but i am wanting to also increase the variable Label_1 by +1 increment each time.

For example, it should do somthing like this:

```
Label_1['text'] = static_webpage_1_titles[0]
Label_2['text'] = static_webpage_1_titles[1]
Label_3['text'] = static_webpage_1_titles[2]
```

Here is my current code:

```
def Generate_Product_Name_and_Price_1():
    if Button_on:
        Find_static_webpage_1()
        for i in range(len(static_webpage_1_titles)):
            Label_1['text'] = static_webpage_1_titles[i]
```

EDIT:

```
product_labels = [Label_1['text'], Label_2['text'], Label_3['text'],
                  Label_4['text'], Label_5['text'], Label_6['text'],
                  Label_7['text'], Label_8['text'], Label_9['text'],
                  Label_10['text']]
```

I have created a list above with each label widget and changed the last line of code in my loop to:

```
def Generate_Product_Name_and_Price_1():
    if Button_on:
        Find_static_webpage_1()
        for i in range(len(static_webpage_1_titles)):
            product_labels[i] = static_webpage_1_titles[i] +': $'+ static_webpage_1_price[i]
```

When i run this, i do not receive any IDLE error but my label widgets do not get populated with data.

Comment: That's possible, but it's a very bad idea. It would be much better to put the Labels in a list, and then index the list.

Comment: @Novel: it's not impossible, but you're right that it's definitely something you shouldn't do unless you fully understand why you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a list of the Label instances, not the text attributes of Label instances. Like this:

```
product_labels = [Label_1, Label_2, Label_3,
                  Label_4, Label_5, Label_6,
                  Label_7, Label_8, Label_9,
                  Label_10]
```

Then you access the attribute like this:

```
for i in range(len(static_webpage_1_titles)):
    product_labels[i]['text'] = static_webpage_1_titles[i] +': $'+ static_webpage_1_price[i]
```

You could also make this a little neater with zip():

```
for label, title, price in zip(product_labels, static_webpage_1_titles, static_webpage_1_price):
    label['text'] = title +': $'+ price
```